# SFC found errors, DISM named the errors, but how can I fix them on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dism, sfc

My computer crashed while running an old game not really meant for Windows 7. After every unexpected shutdown, I run `sfc /scannow` and this time it came back with errors. A long log, 12000 lines of basically nonsense. While looking into it, I discovered DISM and that there is a shim for it to work on Win7. I run `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /scanhealth` and it produces this log (much shorter than `sfc`):

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.18489
2014-08-06 10:35

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum       Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~10.2.9200.16437.mum does not match the actual file name
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x00000000  servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum      Expected file name Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~neutral~~10.2.9200.16437.mum does not match the actual file name

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 140
 Found 2 errors
  CBS MUM Corrupt Total count: 2

Unavailable repair files:
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat
    servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat
```

Since this is on Win7, I can't run `/RestoreHealth` to have it fix any problems. It *seems* like all I need to do is rename these files to include the word `neutral` in the proper places but I absolutely do not want to do that myself.

The system seems fine and stable but I'd still like to fix these issues. Is there maybe a place I can get the cat/mum files to aid in the repair of these issues? Maybe a different command? Maybe boot a Windows CD and do something with the Recovery Console? I'm open to anything.

Comment: put the IE cab to  patch where checksur can pick the file: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2010/05/26/using-checksur-and-update-packages-to-fix-corruption.aspx

Comment: Since the system crashed, I would recommend running this command before proceeding: `chkdsk %systemdrive% /r` This way you can ensure the file system health is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the latest version of the SURT tool? I suspect not since you used a shim to get DISM to produce that log in Windows 7 when it doesn't naturally support that. The SURT (System Update Readiness Tool) is the Windows 7 alternative.

The lines you see in the log are actually due to an old bug in the SURT and its incompatibility with IE10/IE11 (in your case IE10). This has been fixed in the later builds of SURT, so you may be running an older version.

The errors you are seeing in the SURT log are nothing to worry about, and only occur because that version of SURT didn't know about the IE10 packages and therefore flags them as corrupt. Don't try and repair them because they're not actually corrupt! I suspect if you download the latest version from here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/what-is-the-system-update-readiness-tool, you won't see the errors any more.

Comment: Long story short: My computer crashed from a failing video card (way too much dogecoin mining). Your explanation seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may run the SUR tool. It will show you the same errors.

Copy the MUM and CAT files in the log to the folder %windir%\Temp\Servicing\Packages, modifying the name of every file to include "neutral" in the right place.

Rerun the SUR tool, it will fix all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Source [IE 10 Install fails on Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit version](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/ie-10-install-fails-on-windows-7-professional-64/3a8e7165-fa6f-4948-9402-74fa8b75e226?rtAction=1454760396001), answer by [MoonPoint1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a10df421-69a3-4328-a761-437cb426a448)

> I had the same two errors in the CheckSUR.log file produced by the
>   System Update Readiness Tool. Even when I got to the point that the
>   tool was stating it was able to repair those errors, I still could not
>   update Internet Explorer from version 9 to 10 and continued to get the
>   Code 9C59 error message when I tried to do so with Windows Update. 
>   After a day of fruitless attempts to successfully complete the
>   upgrade, I finally found someone suggesting the problem could be fixed
>   using pkgmgr /up commands to uninstall packages from the
>   \Windows\Servicing\Packages directory.
>
> For anyone else who may have found this page while searching for a
>   solution as I did, the following commands resolved the problem for me
>   when I entered them from the \Windows\Servicing\Packages directory:
>
> ```
> pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437
>
> pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437
>
> pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~10.2.9200.16521
>
> pkgmgr /UP:Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~9.4.8112.16421
> ```

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). I've fixed the quoting for you this time.